# Fire a Javascript Function OnSelect subgrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm facing a issue that I need to call a javascrip function when the user select any row of a SubGrid.

Scenario:
I have two grids, the first one shows accounts records, the second one is supposed to show all the Phones related with the account record that I selected on the first grid.

Is that possible?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

CRM Javascipt SDK doesn't support any of those features. You should probably have a custom ribbon button to handle it. Or you can use jquery to attach some events on the record dom. But, this is not supported by CRM 2011.